# Difference between sending a function as arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen in many place those two options to do the things but don't know which is the difference more exactly between this:

```
<Button onClick={doSomething} title='OK' />
```

and this:

```
<Button onClick={() => doSomething()} title='OK' />
```

Comment: That's like asking what's the difference between you and Ronaldo. On a serious note, its all documented here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: For the simple function above it makes no difference. However, for methods it has to do with the context of `this`. When you call `something.doIt()` the value of the `this` keyword inside the `doIt()` method is `something`. But if you do `x = something.doIt; x()` then the value of the `this` keyword inside the `doIt()` method is either the global object (`window` in web browsers) or undefined. In the first case that is what you are doing - passing a reference to `doSomething` to be called and therefore it is no longer associated with its object.

Comment: Also, there can be arguments passed by the caller of the event handler, such as the event object. If your function would expect different optional arguments, this can lead to problems. If you use an arrow function, you can control yourself what arguments are passed into your handler (none in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button onClick={doSomething} title='OK' />
```

You pass the function reference to the `onClick` event to execute, on my opinion mostly I use it

1. When I just want to execute one function on the `click` event.
2. When I don't need any parameters or just the `event` parameter.

```
<Button onClick={() => doSomething()} title='OK' />
```

you execute the function inside the outer callback, which I usually do when I want to

1. Execute more than one function on the `click`.
2. When I need to pass more parameters to the function than the `event` parameter.

### Some Notes

**Just note you can just pass the function reference and use `bind()` to pass more parameters than the event parameter.**

**For performance optimization, If you use `memo` hook with the child component it would be better to use `useCallback` hook with the function**

Answer (score 1):

When using this:

```
<Button onClick={doSomething} title='OK' />
```

You can't pass parameter to the function.

```
  <Button onClick={() => doSomething()} title='OK' />
```

With this one you can pass a parameter for example

> As @deceze said in the comments: this will receive any argument that you passed from outside not an argument that `onClick` will pass

```
<Button onClick={() => doSomething(row.id)} title='OK' />
```

Comment: Yes and no. `doSomething` will receive whatever argument `onClick` will pass. `() => doSomething()` will *not* receive any argument. `() => doSomething(row.id)` will receive `row.id` as argument, not whatever `onClick` passes.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference, in all honesty.  The named function option allows you to centrally maintain the logic but prevents you from using it directly in various places where the handler signature may vary.

The arrow function form, on the other hand, allows you to "proxy" disparate event function signatures into your own function.  This is something like the Adapter pattern, where you "translate" something (the specific event parameters) into something else (your specific function's parameters).

In short, the arrow function will allow you more flexibility in the long run, but both are the same thing, in essence:  Objects of type function.

Furthermore, arrow functions  cannot get their `this` variable redefined.  If you ever find yourself in need of this, go for the arrow function variant.